# How to make a recursion function on a complicated equation?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I need to make a recursive program which can find the answer to the following equation:

[image: model]

P1(k) is a simple binomial distribution equation.

And the equation, Pn(k), will recursively call itself until it doesn't reach P1(k), which will come as:

[image: model2]

This equation is used to find revenue for some airlines. I have made the functions to find the nCr for the binomial distribution and a separate function for the binomial distribution. This was done because probabilities are extremely small, i.e., they might be equivalent to 10 raised to power -10 or less.

```
class GFG 
{ 
 // function to calculate nCr i.e., number of  
 // ways to choose r out of n objects 
 static int nCr(int n, int r) 
 { 
    // Since nCr is same as nC(n-r) 
    // To decrease number of iterations 
    if (r > n / 2) 
        r = n - r; 

    int answer = 1; 
    for (int i = 1; i <= r; i++) { 
        answer *= (n - r + i); 
        answer /= i; 
    } 

    return answer; 
} 

// function to calculate binomial r.v. probability 
static float binomialProbability(int n, int k, float p) 
{ 
    return nCr(n, k) * (float)Math.pow(p, k) *  
                    (float)Math.pow(1 - p, n - k); 
} 

public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n,k = 1,nn; 
    float p; 

    System.out.println("Enter the number of total trials ");
    n=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the success probability ");
    p=scan.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter the successive number of flights ");
    nn=scan.nextInt();

    float probability = binomialProbability(n, k, p);

    System.out.println( " probability is = " + probability ); 
    scan.close();
} 
}
```

I need to know how do I go about the problem as the equation contains summations which will further complicate the recursion.